# How to use Rake to manage multiple directory project?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a project that consists of multiple projects, something like:

my_project\
  proj_A\
    (code, tests, Rakefile, etc)
  proj_B\
    (code, tests, Rakefile, etc)
  proj_C\
    (code, tests, Rakefile, etc)

I'd like to create a Rakefile under "my_project" that can execute the Rakefile's in the other projects. For example to package up the entire app I need to run tasks defined in the Rakefile's in proj_A, proj_B and then proj_C (in that order).

What's the best way to do this? Just have a Rakefile that defines tasks which call out to the other Rakefiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a rake task that depends on all the other projects.

```
import 'projdir1/Rakefile'
import 'projdir2/Rakefile'

task :finalproject => [:project1, :project2] do
  # do nothing or maybe some cleanup
end
```

The tasks :project1 and :project2 would be defined in the external rakefiles being included.

Also look at this page for more complex examples.
http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html

Comment: what is ":project1" referring to? I presume a task in "this" Rakefile. So what's the proper way to load another Rakefile so I can invoke it's tasks?

Comment: I've updated the comment with how to load external rakefiles. They're just ruby files after all but you'll need to include them using 'import' instead of 'require'. Require adds a '.rb' suffix to the file name before it starts searching for it.